# Google App Engine - Will the Id of a datastore entity ever be negative?

Tags: google-app-engine

Will the Id of a datastore entity ever be negative? Or are they guaranteed to be positive numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

<strike>More text to make SO happy with my answer.</strike>

Comment: Does this still hold true? Now that they are using this: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html

Answer (score 6):

I cannot find a doc stating it explicitly, but I have never seen one that is negative.  The [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html#Paths_and_Key_Uniqueness) do say that id's generally increase as new entities are created. (But they should not be relied upon to be strictly so, as you might get id's slightly out of order, like 10,11,13,12,14)

Comment: More than 'slightly' out of order - IDs are allocated to App servers in blocks of 1000, so you might get IDs in order 1001, 2001, 1002, 1003, ...