# Ok to use negative id's for datastore entities?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to re-visit [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828676/google-app-engine-will-the-id-of-a-datastore-entity-ever-be-negative), which says that the datastore can never have negative ID's, but is for the old M/S datastore and I believe no longer applies.

(Note that this question is distinct from the common question about the auto-generate functionality, which still does not produce negative numbers.)

I find that the consensus of SO is that the datastore does not support negative id's, yet I've been using them for one of the Kind's in my app.

I manually assign the negative numbers to the (Java) long id field of my entities' when I created them.  When I view the entities in the GAE console data viewer they appear correctly as negative numbers, e.g. "id=-8673495404141992816".

Perhaps the idea that the DS doesn't support negative ID's is just a relic of the M/S datastore, or perhaps I have unintentionally gone into unsupported and uncharted territory - in which case I should change my app!

Also, IMO, this is a fairly fundamental question in regard to the DS, so I want to be clear about the answer.  After all, I'd like to have the option to generate ID's using a 64-bit hash function which could produce negative numbers.

Comment: Why not store the hash as a string, and then not have any potential issues, that we are not aware of.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question ;-)

Comment: Some of the entities also have be stored in an SQLite db on the client, so it makes it easier if I have a long id.  Also, the string is long I think it is more efficient to use the long id instead.

Comment: Yep your probably right. The only question is what is appengine team not telling us ;-)

Answer (score 0):

IDs appear to be 64-bit values.  However, the default app id generator limits them to postive 53 bit values so that they will work with Javascript.  You're probably floating around in uncharted territory.

Or at the very least, rarely used territory.

Comment: I would be hesitant to limit myself to the range used by the current auto-generate - as you point out, that limits me to 53 of the potential 63 or 64 bits (depending on whether negatives are ok).  That's a massive loss for a hash function.

Comment: Depends what you're using it for.  If you have a web frontend, not having to worry about your Javascript program flailing with large IDs is probably worth it, but if you're using another client, then you're right, no need to limit yourself.  But then you'd have to come up with your own ID generator, which is surprisingly hard on GAE if you want uniqueness.

Comment: My front-end is Android only, but your point is worth considering.